# how do i continuously get the read more link if i have long content on a particular div using jquery

Tags: jquery, continuous

i want to break my content div into 4 readmore links

```
<div id="mycontent">
testing long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long contenttesting long content
</div>
```

how can i do it usuing jquery
Please help me in

Comment: well I think you should give us a condition of where do you want to break/devide it... e.g. number charactes, or words, or something else

Comment: Yeah, more explanation is needed. What do they link to?

Comment: <div id="mydiv"> content area </div> i want this content are to divide into 4 parts means i dont want to show the full content when the page loads when page loads i want some portion of that content will show and that *content area * will be shown with read more link and again i clicked on the read more link it shows another part of that content.

i want to show the content part should be divide into 3 readmore links

Comment: @Gurpreet: Should it always be four parts, or is that just an example for this specific input? Be more precise, please.

Comment: its not necessary that it should be 4 time it just an example i gave to understand my problem
Thanks

Comment: @Gurpreet Singh I dont think you understand, you are asking us to cut a cake, not telling us if you want the cake halfed, in 4 equal pieces, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much of jQuery you know but this is a nice plugin you can use.

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html

there is a demo and the download link there aswell :) hope it helps